# django- my form has attrubute 'password_confirm' but in view not known

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

in my form i added a variable named 'password_confirm'. but in view, django does not know it.
in the html file, i created a form manually.

my form code:

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.Form):
name = forms.CharField(required=True,)
family = forms.CharField(required=True)
username = forms.CharField(required=True)
email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
password = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
password_confirm = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
type = forms.CharField(max_length=1)


def clean_password(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pas1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
    pas2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password_confirm')
    if pas1 != pas2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("password and confirmation not matched!")

    return super(UserRegisterForm, self).clean()

def clean_email(self):
    email_qs = User.objects.filter(email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
    if email_qs.exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("this email already exists!")
```

this is my form element:

```
<input type="password" name="password_confirm" id="confirm-password" tabindex="8" class="form-control" placeholder="confirm" dir="rtl"/>
```

and this is the view:

```
def register_view(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save(commit=False)
    password = form.cleaned_data['password']
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    profile = Profile()
    profile.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    profile.family = form.cleaned_data['family']
    profile.name = form.cleaned_data['email']
    profile.type = form.cleaned_data['type']
    profile.save()
    login(request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

this is the error:
KeyError at /register/
'password_confirm'

what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of form's fields matters. Since `password` defined before `password_confirm` in `clean_password` method `password_confirm` is empty.
You need to perform password check in `clean_password_confirm` method, just rename it:

```
def clean_password_confirm(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```